# Xorg doesn't properly work on RPI3

Tags: video, pi-3b+

I'm trying to configure Xorg on my Raspberry Pi 3 (Model B). I've just installed Debian GNU/Linux (`unstable/arm64`) and it runs. Then, I've decided to install Xorg, LightDM, and i3 but I'm having issues with i3 (and Xorg in general). Windows rendering seems failing (e.g. I cannot see all text elements).

I've modified `cma` in `/boot/firmware/cmdline.txt` (see below). It helped me to fix an issue on Xorg loading, but no progresses in configuration.

```
console=tty0 console=ttyS1,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes net.ifnames=0 cma=256M rootwait
```

Herein the `dmesg` output.

```
[   95.147215] WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 389 at drivers/gpu/drm/vc4/vc4_plane.c:792 vc4_plane_async_set_fb+0x7c/0x88 [vc4]
[   95.157733] Modules linked in: ip6t_REJECT nf_reject_ipv6 nft_counter ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_tcpudp xt_comment nft_compat nf_tables nfnetlink nls_ascii nls_cp437 vfat fat vc4 evdev joydev snd_soc_core snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_pcm brcmfmac snd_timer snd hid_generic soundcore brcmutil cec usbhid smsc95xx cfg80211 drm_kms_helper usbnet hid mii rfkill drm vchiq(C) bcm2835_rng bcm2835_thermal pwm_bcm2835 rng_core bcm2835_wdt leds_gpio ip_tables x_tables autofs4 ext4 crc16 mbcache jbd2 crc32c_generic fscrypto ecb aes_arm64 dwc2 udc_core usbcore sdhci_iproc sdhci_pltfm sdhci usb_common bcm2835 i2c_bcm2835 phy_generic
[   95.213067] CPU: 3 PID: 389 Comm: Xorg Tainted: G         C        4.19.0-1-arm64 #1 Debian 4.19.12-1
[   95.222419] Hardware name: Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2 (DT)
[   95.228337] pstate: 80000005 (Nzcv daif -PAN -UAO)
[   95.233214] pc : vc4_plane_async_set_fb+0x7c/0x88 [vc4]
[   95.238528] lr : vc4_plane_async_set_fb+0x30/0x88 [vc4]
[   95.243825] sp : ffff00000bae38a0
[   95.247183] x29: ffff00000bae38a0 x28: ffff888b2ea95500
[   95.252574] x27: 00000000fffffffc x26: 000000000000041a
[   95.257965] x25: 0000000000000040 x24: 0000000000000040
[   95.263355] x23: 0000000000000000 x22: ffff888b3769e500
[   95.268745] x21: ffff888b38914418 x20: ffff888b2ea95500
[   95.274137] x19: ffff888b37bb0600 x18: 0000000000000000
[   95.279529] x17: 0000000000000000 x16: 0000000000000016
[   95.284922] x15: 0000000000000040 x14: ffff888b38567700
[   95.290314] x13: 0000000000000004 x12: 0000000000000001
[   95.295704] x11: 0000000000000000 x10: 00000000fffffffc
[   95.301095] x9 : 0000000000001000 x8 : ffff888b376c4cf0
[   95.306486] x7 : 0000000000000045 x6 : ffff888b36174678
[   95.311877] x5 : 0000000000000017 x4 : 0000000000000016
[   95.317267] x3 : ffff888b361753a0 x2 : 00000000fffffffc
[   95.322657] x1 : ffff888b37bb0600 x0 : ffff888b37611600
[   95.328049] Call trace:
[   95.330543]  vc4_plane_async_set_fb+0x7c/0x88 [vc4]
[   95.335503]  vc4_plane_atomic_async_update+0x40/0xf0 [vc4]
[   95.341093]  drm_atomic_helper_async_commit+0x5c/0x110 [drm_kms_helper]
[   95.347817]  vc4_atomic_commit+0x80/0x180 [vc4]
[   95.352476]  drm_atomic_commit+0x54/0x60 [drm]
[   95.357004]  drm_atomic_helper_update_plane+0x104/0x128 [drm_kms_helper]
[   95.363843]  __setplane_atomic+0xf0/0x150 [drm]
[   95.368479]  drm_mode_cursor_universal+0x124/0x240 [drm]
[   95.373910]  drm_mode_cursor_common+0x180/0x1f0 [drm]
[   95.379074]  drm_mode_cursor2_ioctl+0x34/0x48 [drm]
[   95.384058]  drm_ioctl_kernel+0xc0/0x110 [drm]
[   95.388601]  drm_ioctl+0x23c/0x3d8 [drm]
[   95.392586]  do_vfs_ioctl+0xc4/0x890
[   95.396213]  ksys_ioctl+0x84/0xb8
[   95.399576]  __arm64_sys_ioctl+0x28/0x38
[   95.403560]  el0_svc_common+0x94/0xe8
[   95.407276]  el0_svc_handler+0x38/0x78
[   95.411081]  el0_svc+0x8/0xc
[   95.414000] ---[ end trace f06603376b8074cc ]---
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: check the release notes of the unstable Debian distro for any references to problems with Xorg ..... you could also try installing a stable release of Debian

Comment: It seems the issue is related to i3wm. I'm trying other window managers.